# Dump a json response to a file

Tags: c#

how do you dump a json response to a file?

Basically I can’t hit the api directly, so for debugging reasons I would like to dump the response to a file on the hosting server then download the file, where I can work with it.

Comment: This is not a how to site you should provide a concise example fo what you have tried already to solve your problem error messages and debuggin code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply dump to a file do this:

```
[... //Do your WebRequest...]

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    //Here you got the JSON as string:
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    // Write the text to a new file named "Response.json".
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Response.json", result );

    return result;
}
```

**Note** this will overwrite your file everytime your getting the response.
In order to prevent that you could add a timestamp to the fileName.

```
//This will (atleast every second) create a unique filename
string filePath = $@"C:\temp\Response{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")}";
```

**Edit:**

To ensure your files are transfered to your `bin\Debug` folder you could use the following:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"Response{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")}");
```

Comment: Thanks Nudity, silly question here, but how would you work out the filepath if the website is hosted on hosting company web server? would it not be   File.WriteAllText("Response.json", result ); Then the file will be placed in the debug folder?

Comment: @Tom yeah I guess so :D It should be place where ever your app is running. Just test it out :D

Answer (score 2):

You can define custom `DelegatingHandler`:

```
public class LogResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //log response string to file

        return response;
    }
}
```

Register it in `HttpConfiguration`

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LogResponseHandler());
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, I never worked with DelegatingHandler

Comment: It should be injected into web api pipeline and it will log **all** responses of this api.